# Подключение PhpSpreadsheet в Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

В абсолютно стандартном проекте laravel не могу понять как подключить данную библиотеку через app.php, свои классы там регистрировал и проблем не возникало, тут в полном замешательстве.

Пробовал так

```
    /*
     * Package Service Providers...
     */
    PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet::class,
    PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx::class,
    ...
```

и прописывать

```
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;
```

В файлах где необходимо это использовать, но к сожалению сталкиваюсь с ошибкой

```
Call to undefined method PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet::isDeferred()
```

Laravel-excel не использую потому что очень много сделано именно на PHPSpreadsheet, а времени переносить нет.

Если получится все взаимодействие свести через алиас Excel (как это делается с laravel-excel) было бы здорово.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. [Устанавливаем](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6#installation) laravel
2. [Устанавливаем](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/#installation) PhpSpreadsheet
3. В laravel создаёт тестовый контроллер `php artisan make:controller TestController`
4. Прописываем роут в `routs\web.php` - `Route::get('/test', 'TestController@index');`
5. Открываем контроллер `TestController` и делаем его таким

По факту делаем так, как [в примере](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/#hello-world) в документации

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;

class TestController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
        $sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
        $sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello World !');

        $writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
        $writer->save('hello world.xlsx');

        return 'ok';
    }
}
```

Созданный файл `hello world.xlsx` можно найти в папке `public`